# Mark cells according different value

Tags: reporting-services

Is there any way to mark cells which contains different value from other in group?
Examle:

```
GroupId | Col1   | Col2
1       |    1   |    2
1       |    1   |    2
2       |    5   |    2
2       |    6   |    2
3       |    1   |    4
3       |    1   |    4
3       |    1   |    5
4       |    3   |    1
4       |    3   |    4
```

- In the first group(GroupId=1) value in cell same, there nothing to do
- In the second group (GroupId=2) value cell in column Col1 is different and I need mark cells in GroupId=2 Col1 in red
- In the third group (GroupId=3) in Col2 there different value and need mark all cells in Col2 for GroupId=3 in red

P.S. value can be string or digits, size of group >= 2 row

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this will be to add a field to your query, or a second query to you report.

A second data set might be something like

```
SELECT
GroupID,
CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Col1) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HighlightCol1,
CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Col2) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HighlightCol2
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY GroupID
```

Then you can set a formula using the [`LOOKUP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx) function (added in SSRS 2008R2) which will retrieve a value from a second dataset based on a reference value in the current dataset.

```
=IIF(LOOKUP(
        Fields!GroupID.Value,
        Fields!GroupID.Value,
        Fields!HighlightCol1.Value,
        "DataSet2Name") = 1,
     "red",
     "white")
```

If you are using SSRS earlier than 2008R2, I'd look at adding new fields to your current dataset. Then you can skip the LOOKUP function.

You can accomplish the same thing in the report layer, but that will be a little more complicated than the above solution.